# how to calculate step size for uniform quantizer?

Tags: discrete-signals, quantization

so I am a little bit confused about the formula of the step size in a uniform quantizer.

from what I have studied:

StepSize = $\displaystyle\frac{maxValue-minValue}{2^n}$, where `n` is the number of bits.

so for example, if we have a signal that changes from (-6 to 6) and the number of bits is 3 bits (also suppose it's midrise).

so according to the formula:

StepSize = $\displaystyle\frac{6-(-6)}{2^3}$ = 1.5

so the possible values for a signal that it could take are:

**-6, -4.5, -3, -1.5, 0, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6**

which are 9 levels not 8 so it needs 4 bits, not 3, also if it's a midrise signal then it shouldn't have a value at zero. so is there anything that I misses here?

Comment: Hi! You can read about [Lloyd-Max quantizer](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee398a/handouts/lectures/05-Quantization.pdf) to get a better appreciation of this topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step size is correctly computed as the OP has shown. The difference between mid-tread and mid-riser is the range within those steps that are used to map to the quantized values.

With reference to the convenient graphic below from this [Georgia Tech course pdf](https://hasler.ece.gatech.edu/Courses/ECE1882/Unit1/DigitalSignals.pdf) by Drs. Butera and Williams (Intro to ECE Design):

[image: mistep and misrise]

The OP has computed $\Delta$ to be 1.5 and is using a midrise quantizer. As we see in the graphic, $V_{min}$ is at $-4\Delta = -6$ and $V_{max}$ is at $+4\Delta = +6$. Where to be clear $V_{min}$ and $V_{max}$ are ranges on the input that are within the maximum quantization error; extending the range further would result in "clipping error".  So far so good. What we also see, is that the output binary values represent values symmetrically about $0$ extending to $\pm 7\Delta/2$. With that all input values $v(t) \in [-4\Delta, -3\Delta) = [-6, -4.5)$ map to $-7\Delta/2 = -5.25$, and so on over the range of input values. The the possible values that the signal can take once quantized are:

$$-5.25, -3.75, -2.25, -.75, 0.75, 2.25, 3.75, 5.25$$

The midrise quantizer is conveniently symmetric about zero, but since it does not include zero it will be more sensitive to noise at low signal levels. The midstep quantizer, although conveniently including zero for minimizing the small signal noise, will have an offset: the signed quantization extends more negative than positive (as is commonly done for signed fixed point representations). The offset becomes insignificant for larger quantization levels, so the noise reduction benefit is generally preferred.

Comment: It's just the [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), Dan.  Nothing more.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Are you referring to my [ ) instead of [ ]?

Comment: No, the OP question.

Comment: If he wasn't midrise that would be the case, if you are referring to the extra 6

Comment: doesn't matter if the OP is midrise or midtread.  The step size for a uniform quantizer is always:

$$ \Delta = \frac{V_\text{max} - V_\text{min}}{2^n - 1} $$

if $n$ is the number of bits.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I think it's what you define $V_{max}$ and $V_{min}$ by. The Georgia Tech course I linked and in Oppenheim in Schafer both do it as the OP had done originally but then together with the mid-riser, mid-tread graphs and definitions as I had provided. Certainly it looks to me for $V_{max}$ and $V_{min}$ as given in the graphics here it is $\Delta = \frac{V_{max}-V_{min}}{2^n}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The example I show seems to make perfect sense as written: there are 8 levels, range in -6 to +6 with steps of 1.5, and as mid riser, the first range is -6 to -4.5 with the resulting quantized value right in the middle as -5.25.  That doesn't work if we make the steps 12/7.

Comment: No it doesn't.  You're going from $-4\Delta$ to $+3\Delta$.

Comment: The graphic I show on the right is going from $-4\Delta$ to $+4\Delta$.

Comment: No it's not.  It's going from $-\frac72 \Delta$ to $+\frac72 \Delta$.

Comment: I see you are referring to the output levels, where I am using the input levels as $V_{max}$ and $V_{min}$  as shown on the graphic. That is going from -6 to +6 when the $\Delta = 1.5$  Any input in the range of 4.5 to 6 maps to $+\frac{7}{2}\Delta$

Comment: But I see how your formula works for the output range.

Comment: Why do you stop where you do on the input?  The horizontal lines extend forever.  You can have $V_\text{max} =  +\infty$ and $V_\text{min} =  -\infty$.

Comment: You stop when the error gets to q/2, within that range up to vmax and vmin its the max quantization error as in every level. Given the formula the OP originally posted, I believe he was using an input range within that restriction although that should be clarified. That is clearly what is indicated in the plots I show. (The Vmax and Vmin is noted).

Comment: Here is yet another independent example (Slide 7 on https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/~yao/EE3414/quantization.pdf) where they use that same convention. Seems pretty common.   There they refer to a "peak-peak range" on the horizontal axis, and generally that range is associated with "full scale" where if you go beyond you start getting clipping noise which is above and beyond the quantization noise already set.

Comment: I think as long as that is all specified / clarified, it works out just fine but as you are pointing out there is plenty of room for confusion if those items aren't defined (so I clarified it in the answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144502/discussion-between-dan-boschen-and-robert-bristow-johnson).

Comment: Dan, as you might remember from before, I don't do side chats.

Comment: @Robert I do! I just pushed the button asking if I would like to automatically move the discussion to chat thinking it would clean up the thread from our concluded side discussion, but it just posted that note instead, so whatever.